# python matplotlib: label in histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am using Python (3.4) Jupyter Notebook. I tried to plot a histogram with label using the code below.

```
   %matplotlib notebook
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib
    import numpy as np

    bins = np.linspace(0, 1.0, 40)

    plt.hist(good_tests, bins, alpha = 0.5, color = 'b' , label = 'good')
    plt.show()
```

But the label 'good' doesn't show at all. Did I miss anything? Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you need to add a legend. See [legend](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html#legend-guide) for details.

```
plt.legend()
```